# How to proof supremum and infimum

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I am having trouble with the following question:

> Let $M=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\colon y=-4x+10 \text{ for some } x\in(6,11)\}.$ Show that the least upper bound and greatest lower bound of $M$ are $-14$ and $-34$, respectively.

I know that $M = \{-26, -22, -18\}$, but I don't really know which set $M$ is a subset of. Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: $M$ is a subset of the real numbers, since $x$ and $y$ can be real numbers, not just integers (and in any case, you missed $x=10, y=-30$).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Henry, $x$ is **any** real number between $6$ and $11$, not just one of the integers $\{7,8,9,10\}$. For example, $x$ can be $7.5$, or even $7+\pi/2$.

**Hint**: show that finding the least upper bound is equivalent to finding $\max_{x\in[6,11]} \{-4x+10\}$. Perhaps the continuity of $x\mapsto -4x+10$ is useful here.

You can use the same trick for the greatest lower bound.

Comment: But if M is a subset of the real numbers how can sup(M) = -14 and inf(M) = -34?

Comment: Why can't it be? Think of the set $(-34,-14)$. It has the same supremum and infimum.

Comment: I think you're confused: the real numbers include the integers (i.e. $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{Z}$). Regardless, a supremum/infimum of $M$ does not have to be in $M$; it just has to be in a larger set (in this case, $\mathbb{R}$) with which we are taking the supremum/infimum with respect to. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsMvCk9ZN7w&index=3&list=PL04BA7A9EB907EDAF. Professor Francis Su defines least upper bound at the beginning of this video.